# Defining polygon's area from OpenStreetMap

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, features, area

In OpenStreetMap, I have a multipolygon OSM feature with its relation ID `6040040` ([example](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/6040040)).

[image]

How do I calculate the area of a such features using QGIS?

Comment: I don't know how I can unflag this question. You can use the `QuickOSM` plugin in QGIS and use this query `(relation(6040040);>;);out body;`. Then you get a new polygon layer. In QGIS, use the `Identify` tool, it will give you the area ellipsoidal in sqaure meters.

Comment: @etrimaille question has been reopened if you would like to expand your comment into an answer

Answer (score 3):

You can download the `QuickOSM` plugin in QGIS.

Then, in the `Query` panel, use the following query:

```
(relation(6040040);>;);out body;
```

[image: quickosm plugin]

This will give your polygon layer with the OSM object inside.
You can use the `Identify` tool in QGIS, the small blue `i`, click on your feature and then expand the `Derived` information. You can find the area ellipsoidal in square meters.
[image: identify tool in qgis]